# conditional redirect in web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

I have a web.config redirect section that is intended to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. Here is the redirect section in my web.config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add the STS header in HTTPS responses">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

I am not sure what flexibility can be implemented but I want this section to work as-is EXCEPT for a specific URL. Specifically, I want all HTTP traffic to continue to be redirect from HTTP to HTTPS EXCEPT when the request is HTTP://{HOST}/symphony/default.aspx.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a condition to the rule to match the request HTTP://{HOST}/symphony/default.aspx, and then use the negate attribute to negate the result of matching.

More information about negate you can refer to this link: [Rule pattern properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rule-pattern-properties).

Comment: In addition to @samwu's answer: Add a condition, something in the line of (untested): `<add input="{URL}" pattern="/symphony/default.aspx" negate="true" />`